# bootstrap-validator check form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I am using [1000hz BootstrapValidator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) and after click on button (not submit because I need to stay on page without refresh) I want to check if form is correct.

I just can call `$("#form2").validator('validate');` but I am not able to get return value.

I know about `isDefaultPrevented` but it is called after submit and I do not want submit.

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah one way is to change the from submit button type from `submit` to `button`and handle the validation via click function and count the length if any input field has error `($('#form2').validator('validate').has('.has-error').length)` and handle it with `if/else` condition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
      if ($('#form2').validator('validate').has('.has-error').length) {
        alert('SOMETHING WRONG');
      } else {
        //$("#form2").submit();
        alert('EVERYTHING IS GOOD');
      }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9k9fqoft/)